# Has microsoft stream api been released?

Tags: stream, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-teams

https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-stream-ideas/apis-for-stream/idc-p/1613106#M2960

According to the link, it is said that the stream API will be released in the fourth quarter of 2020. There is no stream api when I searched it, but if you know the link to the stream api or related information, please share it.